# What is Working Holiday Visa?

Tags: visas, working-holiday

Recently I noticed the term *Working Holiday Visa* on several questions here.

**What is exactly a *Working Holiday Visa*?** How does it differ from a *Work Visa* or *Temporary Worker Visa*?

Now I am sure these things vary by country but I am asking for a general definition, just like a visa is something that differs by country yet I know what it means.

Comment: Confusingly, Australia has both a “Working Holiday Visa” and a “Work and Holiday Visa”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Working holiday visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_holiday_visa):

> A **working holiday visa** is a residence permit allowing travellers to undertake employment (and sometimes study) in the country issuing the visa to supplement their travel funds. For many young people, holding a working holiday visa enables them to experience living in a foreign country without undergoing the usual costly expenses of finding work sponsorship in advance or going on expensive university exchange programmes.

As you might imagine, there is a wide variety of rules and conditions for these, depending on the country in question. In general, a working holiday visa is valid for a longer period of time than a regular tourism visa, and is generally only available for young people (typically under 35 or younger).